# How to prevent state loading in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

My component:

```
constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) {

        router.events.subscribe((val) => {
            if (val instanceof NavigationStart && !isloggedIn) {
                console.log(val);
            }
        });
    }
```

If the user is logged in `navigationStart`, I want to prevent the user from loading the page if the user is not logged in. How to do this in angular 2?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guard-admin-feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create `AuthGuard` set it for all routes which user shouldn't land if not's login.

```
const routesConfig: Routes = [
   {
       path: 'admin',
       component: AdminLayoutComponent,
       canActivate: [AuthGuard],        
       children: [
           { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardComponent },            
       ]
   },
   {path: 'admin-login', component: AdminLoginComponent},
   {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
   {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

Here is simple AuthGuard.

```
  @Injectable()
  export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor() {}

   canActivate() {
      let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

      // here do logic for navigate to login if user don't have local storage...

      return true;
      }
   }
```

For more information check this [link](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html).